# Recombine the data from 2 columns in Excel into a single column

Tags: excel

I am limited to using Excel 2016. I know in Python I can achieve this very easily, but looking for a solution to make my life easier. I have a fairly large dataset which -generally- looks like the table below (the real dataset also broken into 3 shifts, but I have simplified it a bit):

*Notes on the dataset*

- The shift managers are consistent about recording data with a "/" character when they do a product changeover in the **Product** and **Output** columns.
- The shift managers are consistent in using a "/" character to show which employees worked on which machines
- Employees **can and do work** across machines in the same shift.
- There are never more than 3 employees on 1 machine
- There are never more than 2 products on each shift

***Example raw data***

| Date | Machine No. | Product | Output | Employees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Aug-2022 | 1 | ABC | 3,100,100 | BOB/JON |
| 01-Aug-2022 | 2 | DCE | 2,300,000 | BOB/CATH/AMY |
| 01-Aug-2022 | 3 | EFG | 4,500,6000 | ZEE/IAN/GAZ |
| 02-Aug-2022 | 1 | ABC/HIJ | 1,100,100/900,000 | BOB/JON |
| 02-Aug-2022 | 2 | DCE | 2,300,000 | AMY |
| 02-Aug-2022 | 3 | EFG | 4,500,6000 | ZEE/IAN/GAZ |
| 03-Aug-2022 | 1 | HIJ/LMN | 1,100,100/1,900,000 | BOB |
| 03-Aug-2022 | 2 | DCE | 2,300,000 | GAZ |
| 03-Aug-2022 | 3 | EFG/PQR | 1,500,600/1,700,000 | ZEE/IAN/JON |

***What I have done so far...***

I can use the "Text to Data" function in Excel, using the "/" character as a delimiter, to create new columns, which results in something like this:

| Date | Machine No. | Product1 | Product2 | Output1 | Output2 | Employee1 | Employee2 | Employee3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/Aug/2022 | 1 | ABC |  | 3,100,100 |  | BOB | JON |  |
| 01/Aug/2022 | 2 | DCE |  | 2,300,000 |  | BOB | CATH | AMY |
| 01/Aug/2022 | 3 | EFG |  | 4,500,6000 |  | ZEE | IAN | GAZ |
| 02/Aug/2022 | 1 | ABC | HIJ | 1,100,100 | 900,000 | BOB | JON |  |
| 02/Aug/2022 | 2 | DCE |  | 2,300,000 |  | AMY |  |  |
| 02/Aug/2022 | 3 | EFG |  | 4,500,6000 |  | ZEE | IAN | GAZ |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 1 | HIJ | LMN | 1,100,100 | 1,900,000 | BOB |  |  |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 2 | DCE |  | 2,300,000 |  | GAZ |  |  |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 3 | EFG | PQR | 1,500,600 | 1,700,000 | ZEE | IAN | JON |

***What I want to achieve...***

My ideal output would be the following:

1. When there are product changeovers on a shift, I would like the additional columns to be reintegrated back into the table, (as below)
2. I want to count the number of unique employees for each shift. I currenlty have a formula to count this, `=SUMPRODUCT(($AJ$48:$AL$56<>"")/COUNTIF($AJ$48:$AL$56,$AJ$48:$AL$56&"")` , but I have to manually update the formula for every shift.

| Date | Machine No. | Product | Output | Employee1 | Employee2 | Employee3 | Total Employees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/Aug/2022 | 1 | ABC | 3,100,100 | BOB | JON |  | 7 |
| 01/Aug/2022 | 2 | DCE | 2,300,000 | BOB | CATH | AMY | 7 |
| 01/Aug/2022 | 3 | EFG | 4,500,6000 | ZEE | IAN | GAZ | 7 |
| 02/Aug/2022 | 1 | ABC | 1,100,100 | BOB | JON |  | 6 |
| 02/Aug/2022 | 1 | HIJ | 900,000 | BOB | JON |  | 6 |
| 02/Aug/2022 | 2 | DCE | 2,300,000 | AMY |  |  | 6 |
| 02/Aug/2022 | 3 | EFG | 4,500,6000 | ZEE | IAN | GAZ | 6 |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 1 | HIJ | 1,100,100 | BOB |  |  | 5 |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 1 | LMN | 1,900,000 | BOB |  |  | 5 |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 2 | DCE | 2,300,000 | GAZ |  |  | 5 |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 3 | EFG | 1,500,600 | ZEE | IAN | JON | 5 |
| 03/Aug/2022 | 3 | PQR | 1,700,000 | ZEE | IAN | JON | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm
- You will also need a Custom Function for this method
- After doing the above:

  - Right Click in the Queries window (on the left)
  - `New Query => Other Sources => Blank Query`f
  - Paste the Custom function into that window
  - Rename the Custom function as per the notes

***Main Code***

```
let

//Read in Data
//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//set data types
//seting "Output" to type text for the "split"
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Machine No.", Int64.Type}, {"Product", type text}, {"Output", type text}, {"Employees", type text}}),

//Unpivot the columns we want to split into rows
//   This would be the Product and Output columns
// then split them into rows
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Date", "Machine No.", "Employees"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns", {{"Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Value"),

//Pivot with no aggregation
//  Because of multiple items in each category, this is best done with a custom function
    Pivot = fnPivotAll(#"Split Column by Delimiter","Attribute","Value"),

//Set the data types, then re-order the columns and split the Employee column into a maximum of three new columns
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Pivot,{{"Product", type text}, {"Output", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Date", "Machine No.", "Product", "Output", "Employees"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Employees", 
            Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
            {"Employees.1", "Employees.2", "Employees.3"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Employees.1", type text}, {"Employees.2", type text}, {"Employees.3", type text}}),

//Group by shift (= data?)
// Then count the distinct employees for each shift
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type2", {"Date"}, {
        {"Count", each _, type table [Date=nullable date, #"Machine No."=nullable number, Product=nullable text, Output=nullable number, Employees.1=nullable text, Employees.2=nullable text, Employees.3=nullable text]},
        {"Total Employees", each 
            List.Count(
                List.Distinct(
                    List.RemoveNulls(
                        List.Combine(
                            Table.ToColumns(
                                Table.SelectColumns(_, List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(_),3))))))), Int64.Type}
    }),

//Re-expand the grouped table
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"Machine No.", "Product", "Output", "Employees.1", "Employees.2", "Employees.3"}, {"Machine No.", "Product", "Output", "Employees.1", "Employees.2", "Employees.3"})
in
    #"Expanded Count"
```

***Custom Function**
Rename `fnPivotAll`*

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

//Rename:  fnPivotAll 

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

***Source Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the world of Excel Power Query. I can see this is a very powerful toolkit and might be very helpful, if I can learn to master it. 

The code you have posted works for the problem, as I wrote it. Although I did have to slightly change it. I updated the Date, to ```"Date", type datetime``` and now the data is broken down by shift. 

In the *"Machine No."* column the data is stored as text (i.e. "Machine 1, Machine 2, Machine 3") is there a quick way to transform this to integer?

Comment: @hamslice Glad to help.  But I don't understand your question.  In the *"Machine No"* column of the data you provided, the values are already stored as integers.  eg: `1, 2, 3`.  Is your actual data really `Machine 1, Machine 2` instead of just the integers you provided in your example?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. In my explanation of the question posted above I made some simplifications. You correctly guessed that the actual data reads ```Machine 1, Machine 2, Machine 3``` etc..   

I have figured out that since (luckily) there are only 9 machines, I think I can use the formula ```=RIGHT(raw_data!K3,1)``` to convert from text to integer, but this is done separately from the Power Query

Comment: @hamslice In PQ, assuming there is only the single space in the machine name, you can split on the space and return the 2nd item.  Insert a line of code after `Source=`:  `#"Machine to Integer" = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"Machine No.", each Text.Split(_," "){1}}),` and then, on the next code line, change the reference from `Source` to `#"Machine to Integer"`